# Android: Detect app state when goes to the background(not visible to the user)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to detect the app state when goes to the background(not visible) using `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` interface, the issue is that I'm not able to know when it is in this state, because `onActivityStopped` called immediately after `onActivityPaused` when I move the app from foreground to recent task or from foreground to background.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks());
    }

    private static class MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("MyApplication", "onActivityCreated: " + activity.getLocalClassName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
            Log.d("MyApplication", "onActivityStarted: " + activity.getLocalClassName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
            Log.d("MyApplication", "onActivityResumed: " + activity.getLocalClassName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
            Log.d("MyApplication", "onActivityPaused: " + activity.getLocalClassName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
            Log.d("MyApplication", "onActivityStopped: " + activity.getLocalClassName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
            Log.d("MyApplication", "onActivitySaveInstanceState: " + activity.getLocalClassName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            Log.d("MyApplication", "onActivityDestroyed: " + activity.getLocalClassName());
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzHIt.png)

Answer (score 0):

The below method to check the app is in the background.

```
public static bool IsAppInBackground(Context context)
    {
        bool isInBackground = true;

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);

        IList<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.RunningAppProcesses;

        foreach (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo in runningProcesses)
        {
            if (processInfo.Importance == Importance.Foreground)
            {
                foreach (string activeProcess in processInfo.PkgList)
                {
                    if (activeProcess.Equals(context.PackageName))
                    {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any listener I can depend on if I move from the recent task to the home screen, becuase I can't know when the app moves to the background status

Comment: For recent task you can use `private bool IsActivityLaunchedFromHistory()
        {
            return Intent.Flags == ActivityFlags.LaunchedFromHistory;
        }`